# Please explain what does following command mean:

Tags: scripts, awk

```
awk -F'[ ()+:]+' '
```

I use it in my script. With this case I can take the time in brackets from for example:

```
Fri Dec 18 11:13 - 11:15  (00:02)    
Fri Dec 18 09:11 - 19:42 (1+10:31)
```

But how does it work? Could anybody explain me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`awk` splits input record into *fields*, and uses the Field Separator (`FS`) to do so. The `-F` option is used to set `FS`. When `FS` is multiple characters long, it is treated as a regular expression.

In this case, `FS` is `[ ()+:]+`:

- `[...]`, called a bracket expression, is used to match one of many characters. `[ ()+:]` means any one of the space, either parenthesis, `+` or `:` characters.
- `+` after a character or a bracket expression, etc., matches one or more of that character, expression, etc.

So, the pattern means one or more of any of space, either parenthesis, plus or colon.

Splitting into fields using this expression, you'll see that:

- `)` ending the line means the last field is empty
- `1+10:31` and `00:02` both split so that the second and third last fields are the hour and minute, since `+` and `:` are both used to separate fields.